# How to setup Monit with Amazon SES

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, capistrano, amazon-ses, monit

I'm having a hard time setting up my monitrc file. I'm using Capistrano to setup Monit on Amazon EC2, using this tutorial as a guide:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/375-monit

```
set daemon 30

set logfile /home/deployer/apps/example/shared/log/monit.log
set idfile /var/lib/monit/id
set statefile /var/lib/monit/state

set eventqueue
    basedir /var/lib/monit/events
    slots 100

set mailserver email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com port 587
   username "amazon_username" password "amazon_password"
   using TLSV1
   with timeout 30 seconds

set alert alerts@example.com

set httpd port 2812
    allow admin: "admin_password"

check system example_server
  if loadavg(5min) > 2 for 2 cycles then alert
  if memory > 95% for 2 cycles then alert
  if cpu(user) > 75% for 2 cycles then alert

include /etc/monit/conf.d/*
```

Looking at my logs, I'm getting the following error:

> Sendmail error: 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified.

I've tried other things like changing the port to 465, but with similar results.

After googling around, I found this post:

http://syshen.cc/post/14394727394/node-js-upstart-monit-and-aws-ses

It describes how to set up the sender:

> To specify the sender by just “set mail {from: your-name@example.com}”.

But this syntax is nowhere to be found in the Monit documentation.

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Been pulling my hair out on this for a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In monit you need setup the `MAIL-FORMAT` directive:

As per the [documentation](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#message_format):

```
SET MAIL-FORMAT {mail-format}
Example:

 set mail-format {
      from: monit@foo.bar
  reply-to: support@domain.com
   subject: $SERVICE $EVENT at $DATE
   message: Monit $ACTION $SERVICE at $DATE on $HOST: $DESCRIPTION.
            Yours sincerely,
            monit
 }
```

The `from` field has to match the email that you are allowing in SES.